# Laravel Eloquent Multi Tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-8

```
DB::table("game")
                ->join("game_description", "game_description.game_id", "=", "game.game_id")
                ->where("game_description.language_id", "=", getLocaleID())
                ->where("game_description.active", "=", 1)
                ->leftJoin("product_to_game", "product_to_game.game_id", "=", "game.game_id")
                ->leftJoin("product_price", "product_price.product_id", "=", "product_to_game.product_id")
                ->orderBy("product_price.product_price", "DESC");
```

I have to create a query like this (in eloquent model). I have to connect 6-7 tables in one query. Can you help me how can i do that?

Comment: Please don't post images of code, paste the code in a code block in your question. You need to define the relations in your models. This is well documented in the Laravel documentation.

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as a picture as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

You can use Relationships for connecting multiple tables.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I know i have to use eloquent relationships but i dont know how to use, and theres no more resources.